# Swift: Creative, Custom UISwitch

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiswitch

What I want is the following `UISwitch`:

[image]

I have mocked the witch up inside Figma and want to build it inside a `UIView` in my app.

How I can get the standard `UISwitch` to look somewhat like the one above?

Maybe I shouldn't start with a `UISwitch` after all, but with some `UIView` with a `TransitionController` or something. I know that I can tweak a `UISwitch` to some extend, but I feel like it would not be enough to get to this.

Comment: `UISegmentedControl` maybe? I'm wondering though about all the customization possible to match your needs.

Comment: You would need to inherit from `UIControl` if you are going to roll your own. https://factoryhr.medium.com/making-custom-uiswitch-part-1-cc3ab9c0b05b

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! @Andrew I will look into that. Looking at the examples they added, some of them look fairly close to mine except for a few things I could certainly tweak. The main concern is adding text inside, don't know if that is possible.

Comment: `UIControl` inherits from `UIView` so you can add subviews to it. So I don't see an issue with adding labels to it. If you read the further parts of the tutorial it shows text on the switch.